# Move namepaces in soap enevlope to payload level in python

Tags: python, soap, suds

I am using suds-jurko (0.6) with python 2.7

Current soap request generated

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://xxxxx/A" xmlns:ns1="http://xxxxxx/B" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns2:Body>
      <ns1:Request>             
         <Parameter xsi:type="ns1:GetParameter">
            <Identifier xsi:type="ns0:NumberIdentifier">
               <Number>2</Number>
            </Identifier>
         </Parameter>
      </ns1:Request>
   </ns2:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The desired soap request should be

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns1="http://xxxxxx/B" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns2:Body>
      <ns1:Request xmlns:ns0="http://xxxxx/A">            
         <Parameter xsi:type="ns1:GetParameter">
            <Identifier xsi:type="ns0:NumberIdentifier">
               <Number>2</Number>
            </Identifier>
         </Parameter>
      </ns1:Request>
   </ns2:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Question

I am using wsdl to make call. Is there a way by using set-options or some other method in suds by which i can force client to create soap envelope namepsaces at nodes instead of everything at soap:enevlope node

Comment: So what's the specific question?

Comment: Edit your post to ask the question. Don't use the comments for this.

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround to move namspaces. Not sure if its the best way but its working.

```js
 def marshalled(self, context):
        context.envelope.normalizePrefixes()           
        remove = {'1': '1'}

        for prefix, ns in context.envelope.nsprefixes.iteritems():
            if ns != 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope': 
                remove[prefix] = str(ns)                
            
        for prefix, ns in remove.iteritems():
            if prefix != '1':
                context.envelope.clearPrefix(prefix)
        

        body = context.envelope.getChild('Body')
        request = body[0]      
        request.addPrefix('xsi','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance')   

        for prefix, ns in remove.iteritems():
            if prefix != '1':
                request.addPrefix(prefix,ns)
```